# selenium - unable to locate the COMPOSE button in gmail

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I am trying to log in to my gmail, compose an email and send it using gmail. I have written the below code but it is failing in locating the COMPOSING button click.

```
package Selenium;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Email {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.google.co.in");

        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/a")).click();

        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        driver.findElement(By.id("Email")).sendKeys("abhilash.rout8@gmail.com");
        driver.findElement(By.id("Passwd")).sendKeys("password");
        driver.findElement(By.id("signIn")).click();

        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'COMPOSE')]")).click();

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[14]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div[4]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/form/div[2]/div")).sendKeys("abhilash.rout8@gmail.com");

        driver.findElement(By.id("1ys")).sendKeys("Hello");
        driver.findElement(By.id("1zu")).sendKeys("Selenium Email");
        driver.findElement(By.id("1yi")).click();
    }
}
```

I am getting the error on `(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'COMPOSE')]")).click();`

I have also tried to find that element by absolute path and css selector also. This error comes in the console when the the Gmail is still loading the email page though I have given it to wait for 2 minutes, I can see it tries to execute the next line when the page is yet to load.

Answer (score 0):

You an try using:

```
WebElement link = driver.findElement(By.linkText("COMPOSE"));
```

Just a suggestion:

Automating Gmail by using the **basic html view** is a lot more easier than using the regular view. When you try to compose an email in the regular view, the small window that pops up has an id that is dynamically generated. This would not be the case in the basic html view. You can load gmail in the basic html view by launching the below url:

> https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/h/s32qz81kdosc/?zy=h&f=1

After logging into the above url, you can find the Compose email link by:

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.linkText("Compose Mail")));
WebElement lnkComposeMail = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Compose Mail"));
lnkComposeMail.click();
```